# Iterating HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to iterate over a HTML file with BeautifulSoup and find the tag with content,"Preferred Name"
Here's the tag I am looking for:(which is a part of file that I want to search through):

```
 <td nowrap class="label">
    Preferred Name
    <span class="slot_labels"></span>
  </td>
```

I tried to search with this(doc is the name of that html file):

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
 tags = soup.fetch('td')
 for tag in tags:
     if tag.contents[0] == 'Preferred Name':
         return tag
```

This code doesn't work, can someone help...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents includes whitespace, so try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
tags = soup.fetch('td')
for tag in tags:
    if tag.contents[0] and tag.contents[0].strip() == 'Preferred Name':
        return tag
```

Comment: It worked! But I had to put the "if" thing inside "try.. except", since some tag's contents[0] is NoneType... Thanks!

Comment: Edited accordingly... but without try...except.